# Additional time stats in football

Tags: football, statistics

Are there any statistics about the additional time that European referees give at the end of both the first and second half of a football game?

I mean for example ,what is the percentage of 1' added time in first half, it must be pretty high! What is the percentage of 3' or 4' added time in second half etc...

Comment: I kept some stats during the first leg of the EURO 2016 taking place these days at France.And here are the results:
In 36 matches 56% of them the referee gave 1' of added time for the first half,36% gave 0 minutes and 8% of them ,the added time for the first half was 2'.
As for the second half , 61%-3' , 17%-5+ , 14%-4' , 8%-2'

Answer (score 2):

After a long search finally found it. [Statsbomb Article](http://statsbomb.com/2017/02/additional-time-spains-missing-minutes/) clearly explain the extra time minute percentage in European 5 top leagues.

These two picture obtained from **Statsbomb website** clearly shows the percentage of time added.

> I am not a original author of these two picture and are obtained from *statsbomb.com* and apparently were made with the data from **Opta**.

Percentage time added in first half:
[image: First Half Data]

Percentage time added in second half:
[image: Second Half Data]