# What is the percentage of goals scored in extra time in the top 5 European leagues?

Tags: football, statistics

I was wondering what the percentage of goals scored in added time (45+1', 45+2', 45+3', ..., 90+1', 90+2', 90+3', ...) is. Are there any statistics showing this?

Ideally, I would be interested in something like (made-up example):

- 1st-half added time: 5%
- 2nd-half added time: 8%

I have found some information, but it's not what I am looking for:

[Additional time stats in football](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/13927/additional-time-stats-in-football)

https://www.soccerstats.com/stats.asp?page=10